# Adding minutes to the current date and create a new row with the spill over minutes

Tags: sql-server

```
C1 | Start_Time      | Minutes
---+-----------------+---------
I1 | 8/6/17 23:50 PM |  40
```

I am using SQL Server, and this is how my table looks like. `Start_Time` of the machine is `'8/6/17 23:50 PM'` continues to run for 40 minutes. By the time when machine stops, it will be next day. In this case the end time is `8/7/17`. Now I need to separate the spill over time and make the next day as new entry.

The result should be like

```
C1  |   Time            | Minutes
----+-------------------+---------
I1  |   8/6/17 11:50 PM |  10
I1  |   8/7/17 12:00 AM |  30
```

The date and minutes must be separated into different rows.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try an insert query which checks if the difference between the `Minutes` and the remaining minutes of a given `Start_Time` on that day is greater than zero.  If so, then do an insert with that difference.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (C1, Start_Time, Minutes)
SELECT
    C1,
    DATEADD(d, 1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, Start_Time)),
    Minutes - DATEDIFF(mi, Start_Time, DATEADD(d, 1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, Start_Time)))
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    Minutes - DATEDIFF(mi, Start_Time, DATEADD(d, 1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, Start_Time))) > 0;
```

Follow the link below for a demo which shows that the insert logic is working correctly.

### Demo

**Edit:**

I just realized that you will also need an update query to adjust the remaining minutes for each record affected by the above insert.  You may use this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Minutes = DATEDIFF(mi, Start_Time, DATEADD(d, 1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, Start_Time)))
WHERE
    Minutes - DATEDIFF(mi, Start_Time, DATEADD(d, 1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, Start_Time))) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks much. It helps